# Using the .p12 certificate iOS apps

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, keychain, provisioning-profile

I am new to iOS development and I am confused about using the .p12 certificate.
I have recieved a .p12 certificate from our client. I installed it and it got added to the KeyChain Access. I want to know how to use it further to make sure my app uses this keychain.

My AppId the developer console shows Game center and in-app purchases as enabled and Push Notifications as configurable.

Any help is appreceiated.

Comment: check this link. it will help you in creating certificates. https://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

Comment: are you got the provisional profile along with .p12]

Answer (score 0):

.p12 file contains the developer certificate and private key which get installed to System keychain when you double click the file and put in the password for .p12 file if asked.
After this you need corresponding provisioning profiles which are using the certificate you received in .p12 file from your client (or if you have access to team account on Apple developer console you can download it from there). Once you get the provisioning profile, you can run the app on simulator and device.